# XLOOKUP to search wildcards between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I need some help with my XLOOKUP. I'm also not sure if I can do this but based on my reading it seems possible.

I have 2 spreadsheets the first is my ChangeMaster which has all my changes I need to verify and the PackProfile sheet which is where I need to verify and update if needed.

Here is what I have so far but it isn't quite right

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,'[MasterChangenotice 1-17.xlsx]ChangeMaster_220116'!$C$2:$C$466,'[MasterChangenotice 1-17.xlsx]ChangeMaster_220116'!$M$2:$M$466,XLOOKUP(N2&"*",'[MasterChangenotice 1-17.xlsx]ChangeMaster_220116'!$M$2:$M$466,'[MasterChangenotice 1-17.xlsx]ChangeMaster_220116'!$M$2:$M$466,0,2))
```

This is my change master file. I'm trying to validate that the unique number in Column C and the Value in Column M are within my pack profile sheet...

[image: ChangeMaster]

... and line up with the unique number in Column C and the highlighted value in my PackProfile sheet below.

[image: PackProfile]

Hopefully I'm explaining this correctly but if any more info is needed I'll be happy to provide it.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ChangeMaster spreadsheet you could create a Validation column to enter the following:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(M2,XLOOKUP(C2,[PackProfile.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,[PackProfile.xlsx]Sheet1!$N:$N)))
```

The above should generate TRUE and FALSE responses from which you could have additional functions triggered.

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick!